# #1093 - You can't specify target table 'cps' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update records that I select

but I got error #1093 and that is my code

```
UPDATE `tabCategories_Products` 
SET`categories` = 'CAT00001' WHERE  `categories` =  'CAT00108'
AND  `parent` NOT IN (

SELECT  `parent` 
FROM  `tabCategories_Products` 
WHERE  `categories` !=  'CAT00108' 
)
```

MYSQL does not allow update on select  , 
so what is the solution for such case 
is there any thing like select for update ?

thanks

Comment: The error message comes from another SQL query.

Comment: @panther: this one should also give the same error.

Comment: It might be a typo, but there is no space between `SET` and the following column try to put a space between them.

Comment: Also, there is no alias name `cps` in your query as the error message suggested, please post the exact query you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your query in the `in` clause in another query :

```
select t.* 
from (
    select  `parent` 
    from  `tabCategories_Products` 
    where  `categories` !=  'CAT00108')
) t
```

This subquery creates an implicit temporary table `t` and doesn't count as a table that you are updating.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps doing a `left join` and then update would be a better idea

```
update tabCategories_Products p1
left join tabCategories_Products p2 on p1.parent = p2.parent 
and p2.categories <> 'CAT00108'
set p1.categories = 'CAT00001' 
where 
p1.categories = 'CAT00108'
and p2.parent is null
```